# ¿Por qué tenemos "whisky" y "güisqui" en el DRAE pero en otros casos no?

Tags: ortografía, rae, dle

Siempre me pareció chocante el hecho que la RAE introdujera "güisqui" en su diccionario:

> **[güisqui](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=iBUwI7UXXDXX2oqN8Mzx)**
>
> (Del ingl. whisky, y este del gaélico uisce beatha, agua de vida).
>
> 1. m. Licor alcohólico que se obtiene del grano de algunas plantas, destilando un compuesto amiláceo en estado de fermentación.

Que a su vez es enlazado desde la también aceptada "whisky":

> **[whisky](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=TDlsr5QGIDXX2GC8Q91C)**
>
> 1. m. güisqui.

¿Qué patrón se siguió en este caso? ¿Por qué por ejemplo no aceptaron "football" y simplemente existe "futbol" / "fútbol"? ¿Subyace alguna norma para estos casos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesante. Después de leer el apartado del DRAE [tratamiento de los extranjerismos](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/que-contiene/tratamiento-de-los-extranjerismos), podría resumir que, la palabra `whisky` ha sido incorporada al diccionario con su grafía original ya que en Español no existe un equivalente que la sustituya completamente. Se añade además `güisqui` como sugerencia de grafía adaptada al Español, mientras la pronunciación es la misma que la de la palabra original. En el caso de la palabra `football`, existe en Español, por uso extendido y popularidad, la palabra `fútbol`, que sustituye a la original completamente, por lo tanto el extranjerismo original no es incluido en el diccionario.